# How accurate should you write item's price and weights for customs when you ship with FedEx?

Tags: international-travel

I have questions about customs duties. Recently I sent a snowboarding bag to New Zealand from tje United States. There was a place FedEx asked me weight and price for all the items in the bag.

I wasn't expectimg that they asked me literally the weights and prices of all items, because I have sent some package with less description but it still got there safely.

I was a little upset since I had to go over 50+ items at the FedEx office.

For future reference, I have two questions.

1. Should I tell them brand new prices, even if I I've owned the item for a few years?
2. What if some of the weights are less than 0.1lb? Should I just say 0 lb for the weight? FedEx says they can't input less than 0.1lb in the system.

Comment: I'm surprised they asked for the weight of items in a bag? Usually what is asked for is the size and weight of each parcel, and the description and value of each item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a customs declaration, it is generally permitted to aggregate categories of items. You can write "Used clothing (personal effects) - 5lb" or something to that effect instead of listing each glove, hat, etc... individually.

New Zealand has [rules for duty-free importation of household goods and personal effects](https://www.customs.govt.nz/personal/duty-and-gst/household-personal-effects-vehicles/), and you'd want to read that and mark the package accordingly, including the required declaration and documents, if you qualify.

It's up to you to determine the [valuation of your goods](https://www.customs.govt.nz/business/import/lodge-your-import-entry/customs-import-value/). Guides to what used items generally sell for at garage sales, charity shops, online auctions, etc... may be useful here if you're unsure.

Answer (score 0):

Did you by any chance piss the people off at the fedex office by being unfriendly or demanding? Because .... 
... there is really no other explanation. Weight for individual items I have never been asked, only total weight and well, thats why they have scales at thge fedex office. Descriptions and prices also are usually approximate, in particular for obvisouly unpacked and used private items.

Comment: It sounds like you have never shipped anything internationally. This is a normal question for such a circumstance.

Comment: @Michael Hampton - I have shipped all over the world. While asking for weight and content is a normal question, the level of details requested in the original question is unusual. If have only ever seen such behavior as "punishment" for particularly sloppy declarations.